# Set Minimum Button Width in Xamarin Forms or iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

We are developing an application using Xamarin Forms, but rely heavily on custom renderers for iOS, including as our button base class. I have a requirement to set all buttons in the application to a minimum width of 120, however it doesn't appear that MinimumWidthRequest accomplishes this. How would I set the minimum width of a button?

Answer (score 1):

try this alternative

```
  var button = new Button();
        if (button.WidthRequest < 120)
        {
            button.WidthRequest = 120;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that only works if the WidthRequest has been set. If it relies on the default, it will truncate the text and make it 120 (smaller than required). I tried checking Width instead of WidthRequest, but had the same issue.

Comment: This code needs to be put in SizeChanged event handler in order for the `button.WidthRequest` to pick up the value.